# IIS - Cors Module - IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, cors

I'm using this in a web.config, and expecting for the subdomains for topdomain and expecting to see the access-control- headers appear in my HTTP responses, but I'm not seeing anything.

It's IIS 8.5.  I've installed the CORS module in IIS.  What am I missing?

I originally manually added headers, but I needed more than just the generic behavior, but instead different behavior per requestor so trying to use CORS.

```
<cors enabled="true">
      <add origin="*" allowed="true"/>
      <add origin="https://*.topdomain.com" allowCredentials="true" maxAge="120">
    <allowMethods>
            <add method="*"/>
    </allowMethods>
    <allowHeaders>
            <add header="*"/>
    </allowHeaders>
      </add>
    </cors>
```

Comment: Usually, we store token or some custom header into the header, so that access-control-request-headers can indicate which HTTP headers can be used after preflight request.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers
At first, you manually added headers, so you can see it in response. When you didn’t add, all requests are anonymous, so you can’t find it.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal i got it to work

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with multiple domains:

```
<cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="false">  
   <add origin="https://*.topdomain.com" allowCredentials="true" maxAge="120"> 
            <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true">
                <add header="DNT" />
                <add header="Host" />
                <add header="Origin" />
                <add header="Referrer" />
                <add header="User-Agent" />
            </allowHeaders>
            <allowMethods>
                 <add method="GET" />
                 <add method="POST" />
                 <add method="PUT" />
            </allowMethods>
            <exposeHeaders>
                <add header="DNT" />
                <add header="Host" />
                <add header="Origin" />
                <add header="Referrer" />
                <add header="User-Agent" />
            </exposeHeaders>
        </add>
        <add origin="https://ourspsubdomain.sharepoint.com" allowCredentials="true" maxAge="120"> 
            <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true">
                <add header="DNT" />
                <add header="Host" />
                <add header="Origin" />
                <add header="Referrer" />
                <add header="User-Agent" />
            </allowHeaders>
            <allowMethods>
                 <add method="GET" />
                 <add method="POST" />
                 <add method="PUT" />
            </allowMethods>
            <exposeHeaders>
                <add header="DNT" />
                <add header="Host" />
                <add header="Origin" />
                <add header="Referrer" />
                <add header="User-Agent" />
            </exposeHeaders>
        </add>
        <add origin="https://localhost:4321" allowCredentials="true" maxAge="120"> 
            <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true">
                <add header="DNT" />
                <add header="Host" />
                <add header="Origin" />
                <add header="Referrer" />
                <add header="User-Agent" />
            </allowHeaders>
            <allowMethods>
                 <add method="GET" />
                 <add method="POST" />
                 <add method="PUT" />
            </allowMethods>
            <exposeHeaders>
                <add header="DNT" />
                <add header="Host" />
                <add header="Origin" />
                <add header="Referrer" />
                <add header="User-Agent" />
            </exposeHeaders>
        </add>
    </cors>
```